# Column 1 with names and Column 2 with values

Tags: mysql, excel

Let's say I have a Text document. There are two columns. Column 1 contains a list of names while column contains a list of value relating to those names. The problem is column 1 may have same names repeating on different rows. This is not an error though.

For ex:

```
Frank Burton 13
Joe Donnigan 22
John Smith   45
Cooper White 53
Joe Donnigan 19
```

What are the ways to organize my data in a way that I would have column 1 with unique data names and column 2 with the values summed together relating column 1? What can I do if I have these data in excel?

For ex:

```
Frank Burton 13
Joe Donnigan 41
John Smith   45
Cooper White 53
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: IS this in mySQL or excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mySQL you could write a query similar to...

`Select col1, Sum(col2) FROM TableName group by col1`

In Excel you could use a pivot table to group the information together
Insert Pivot table, select range enter values as in image below.

[image]